# How to root honor 9 oreo?

Tags: rooting, twrp, 8.0-oreo

I updated my honor 9 to oreo few days ago and I'm trying to root it but i can't find a twrp version for it or another method to root it
I tried an alpha version of twrp and flashed it using fastboot but when i boot into recovery mode i find the stock recovery instead of twrp

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to root using magisk manager via twrp or adb
Checkout this thread https://forum.xda-developers.com/honor-view-10/development/magisk-root-honor-view-10-mate-10-pro-t3749280/amp/